# Can we have the "blatantly off topic" close vote back?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons, custom-close-reasons

Quite often, questions get asked that are really not to do with programming at all. Sometimes they're appropriate for Super User or whatever, but not always. We used to have a **blatantly off-topic (this has nothing to do with programming)** close reason, but it's gone for some reason.

What would we do with

> How do I get a girlfriend?

as a question? It doesn't fit any of the close reasons except for "Other", which seems a bit of a shame when we used to have something purpose-built for it.

Perhaps there's a Stack Exchange site for that, but I wouldn't expect to spend my time finding it. It's so blatantly off topic that the OP should do his own work looking for it.

Comment: Too hard to use the custom close reason?

Comment: "Too broad" ...

Comment: @Louis we could in that case remove everything except "Other"...

Comment: @Jongware I suppose that example was a bit too broad, yes :)

Comment: @chiastic-security *sigh*... You know, taking what someone says and pushing it to *ridiculous extremes* is not a good way to make a point. How often do you need to use the "other" option so as to close a question that has nothing to do with programming? I don't know about you but in my experience it happens several orders of magnitude less often than closing for the other reasons that have their own options.

Comment: @Louis no, I haven't found it to be that rare.

Comment: I thought that was only available when you *flagged* for closure, not casting a vote to close.

Comment: "Too broad."  C'mon.  You can find less-bad examples and link to them instead.

Comment: Easy, just do `girlfriend.get();` and you'll be able to get her. Unless you want a new one, in that case you must do `new Girlfriend();`. You can even choose her name as a parameter in the constructor!

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia Tried invoking your girlfriend constructor and got `Terminated unexpectedly: too many arguments.`

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia -1, doesn't use jQuery.

Comment: @Jongware, `too broad`? or `A broad`?... or `two broads`!

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia: This is why Python is better; the getter only provides a false sense of security, and either way, you're relying on the fact that I'm not going to maliciously steal your girlfriend. Plus, if you're going to try to hide a girlfriend via encapsulation, a giant snake is probably a better hiding place than a cup of coffee.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia: I forgot to `delete` the old `Girlfriend` and my `new Girlfriend()` found me leaking memory while I was sleeping. Plz advise urgentz.

Comment: Well, at least he didn't propose in the first place.. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486419/c-save-int-with-leading-zeros-to-string-not-displaying-them/26486489#comment41607347_26486489)

Comment: `while(girlfriend is null) sleep();` -- why mess with a good thing?

Comment: "Primarily opinion-based"

Comment: `Girlfrind::Girlfriend(string _hair = "Brown", string _eyes = "Blue") : hair(_hair), eyes(_eyes) {}`

Comment: +1 Alternative approach: assume the question is meant within the realm of programming, so the example would be interpreted as, "How do I get a girlfriend _using programming_?" One answer saying create another Facebook, sell to Facebook, get rich; then four votes to close as primarily opinion-based or too broad. I guess that doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You don't even have to type as much as hichris's answer implies - the system already fills in most of this, just put *something* at the end and you're done:

[image]

The more off-topic the question, the less you have to put there - and once *someone* has typed something, every other close voter need only select it from the list; thus, it provides a handy way to coordinate close voters so we don't end up with folks [arguing over whether/why something like this is off-topic](http://www.shog9.com/whydivorce.png).

Comment: Still dislike having to feed a troll with a comment. Also on meta.ELU: [look at Shog9's suggested close reason in the linked MSE answer: is the really closing the question because it's "about personal relationships"? No, he's closing it because it's not about programming.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/7098).

Answer (score 14):

If you're *flagging*, there's a ["Blatantly off-topic" reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185873/165773).

But if you're voting to close, there's the Other reason. And really, is it that hard to put in that box:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the [help/on-topic].

That's 6 added words in addition to the stuff already in the box.

> which seems a bit of a shame when we used to have something purpose-built for it.

Yeah, that was at least over a year ago -- before my time. It's the exact same thing. Just with a *tiny* bit more effort.

Comment: ... is `[help]` a magic shortcut to [help]? By Jove it is--that'll save some typing! Any more of these? To all other SE sites perhaps?

Comment: @Jongware: Even better, make it `[help/on-topic]`, which links to a specific page in the [help/on-topic], like this. And yes, [there are more of these.](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: It's hard to remember, and even harder for new users that don't know that's what they should put. It requires more time to think about what to say, instead of just clicking a button.

Comment: The option to flag as being blatantly off-topic seems to have disappeared once I hit 3,000 rep - now the only choices are Spam, Rude or Abusive, or In Need of Moderator Attention.