# Flagged as Blatantly Off Topic, On Hold as Opinion Based

Tags: support, flags, scope

I'm scratching my head about this one.

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27215492/3899908) as *Blatantly Off Topic*, but it has been put on hold as *primarily opinion-based*. It confuses me how those who voted for the close reason went for this option. It is wildly off topic, the primarily opinion-based part is inconsequential.

Often the close reason changes from the item I flagged a post for, but who decides that the flag is wrong and how can it be changed from the original?

Comment: at Workplace, they have a dedicated close reason for stuff like that: [Questions that focus on ranting about problems rather than trying to solve them](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696)

Comment: The question starts with "Give me your opinion Must !!!" I can see why three people voted that it was an opinion-based question vs. the two who voted that it was off-topic. In either case, the question was closed, as it should be.

Comment: The majority votes decides. Opinion-based won out, it seems.

Comment: I see, but surely my flag should be option #1 (or does it not work like that ... I don't have close vote privileges yet, obviously).

Comment: worth noting that [Blatantly off-topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257935/839601) is available only to flaggers; those who cast votes to close don't have it as predefined option

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we have the "blatantly off topic" close vote back?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274774/can-we-have-the-blatantly-off-topic-close-vote-back)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seemed confused about what your flag does. All your flag does is bump it into the Close Votes queue, where users with close-voting privileges are **reviewing the question** and not your flag. In their dialog, your flag would add a 1 next to the off-topic option. They are not limited, though, to voting to close as off-topic. They can still choose whichever reason they want - whatever they think fits the situation best.

Your flag automatically gets marked helpful under one of these circumstances:

- Someone with full voting privileges casts a vote to close for the same reason you selected.
- The question gets closed for any other reason.

It will only get declined if, during review, three people choose to leave the question open.

This time, there were three people who chose "primarily opinion-based" and only two who chose "off-topic" - so the opinion-based reason won out with the majority and that's what gets displayed in the post notice. There's really nothing else to think about. That's what the community chose, it's closed either way. I wouldn't worry about it. It's already been pointed out in the comments that the question is "wildly off-topic" and it may now begin its path to deletion.