# Off topic questions in [adobe-illustrator] tag

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, clean-up

The [adobe-illustrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-illustrator) tag is a big target for non-programming related questions. Quality aside, some questions are using it as it's supposed to be used (for Applescript and Extendscript, or other SDK related questions), such as these:

- [Place SVG in Illustrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28839109/place-svg-in-illustrator)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28553945/export-or-save-layer-as-ai-document

However, a lot are beginners asking basic questions on how to use the program:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517449/why-can-i-see-contours-through-a-layer-above-in-adobe-illustrator-cs5
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467122/make-part-of-stroked-path-transparent

By definition, I would say the second set of questions would be a better fit on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com, but I wouldn't suggest migrating a lot of them, because of the quality issue.

So, this is really a two-part question:

### What close reason should I use?

Should I flag these as **blatantly off-topic**, since they're not about programming?

### Who wants to help?

This is a low-traffic tag, so even if I flag every question I can (with my 10 flags per day), it just goes into the review queue, never to be seen again. This is basically something that I don't have the rep to handle on my own.

Comment: The ones I just looked at all look like they could fall under the "general computer hardware and software" category, as they are asking how to use a certain program.

Comment: You can always notify the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) that there will be questions coming in for a specific tag, so they don't go unnoticed.

Comment: @KevinBrown Interesting. I always assumed the review queues were First In First Out.

Comment: @DarrickHerwehe The queues can be filtered on tags, afaik. I know the close queue can.

Comment: In additon to what @Kevin said: If you close flag what you can today and tomorrow before the close vote event of 21:00 UTC and leave a message, the [SO Close vote reviewers room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) will take care of them.

Comment: 455 questions lawd

Comment: Maybe somebody (who is not me) should edit the tag wiki and make it clear that questions that have nothing to do with the scripting capabilities of illustrator are offtopic. I saw at least two questions along the lines "not sure if this question is allowed, but I saw that there is a tag".

Comment: @MatthiasBauch That was my first thought. But, the wiki makes it pretty clear that it should only be used for programming question. The excerpt, on the other hand, doesn't. Maybe there's a way to make that more specific?

Comment: Oh, I just looked at the excerpt.

Comment: We had rather good close event with enough people showing up so 5 members reported that the CVQ had no more questions for them on this tag.The report is [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/21914711#21914711). If you flag more feel free to drop a message again.

Comment: @rene That's great! Thanks. I'll probably be adding more throughout this week.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just took a quick look through a few of these questions and started throwing some close votes around.  For the most part, the questions that are off topic are very obvious ("please help me draw this"), but there are quite a few good questions in there about scripting.

> Should I flag these as blatantly off-topic, since they're not about programming?

For the most part, these can be closed off as "Off topic" -> "General computing".

> Who wants to help?

The [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room has been notified. They can help out once questions enter the close queue, but they need to be flagged to get there first.

Comment: Just curious, in a more general setting where a question is talking about software but not about programming, is it always more appropriate to use the "General computing" flag reason over "blatantly off-topic"? Would a flag more likely be declined under "blatantly off-topic" if it could be also flagged under "General computing"?

Comment: @Turnerj There is no pre-defined "blatantly off-topic" reason anymore on SO and I haven't seen once that a custom reason was used today for the cleanup as "blatantly off-topic". Generally this can be pushed to SU, but with some questions you have to ask yourself if they should be. They may be of such poor quality that it is better to close them here and not triggering the migration by using different close reason. I personally like "unclear what you're asking" or "too broad" for this case.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I've just double checked and [there is an off-topic close reason titled "blatantly off-topic"](http://imgur.com/IoePw3O) though I otherwise agree with what you said. I've seen other meta's (particularly Programmers.SE) that are annoyed by the posts migrated over (whether they be crap or still off-topic). Yeah, quite familiar with the "unclear what you're asking" and "too broad" close reasons as I use them quite often in the Triage review queue.

Comment: @Turnerj Thanks, mystery solved: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274780